# Java static access to super

Tags: java

I'm exploring some sample code and I found the following code:

A LoginService interface:

```
public interface LoginService extends Serializable {

      default boolean isLoggedIn (final HttpServletRequest req) {

             return null != PortalUtil.getUserId(req);
      }
}
```

A LoginServiceFactory which contains a nested LoginServiceImpl class which implements LoginService

```
public class LoginServiceFactory implements Serializable {

     private volatile LoginService loginService = null;

     private final class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

          @Override
          public boolean isLoggedIn(final HttpServletRequest req) {

               /** this is the part I don't understand */
               return LoginService.super.isLoggedIn(req);
          }
    }
}
```

I dont understand which method is called in `LoginService.super.isLoggedIn(req)`. From my understanding it's calling `isLoggedIn(req)` of the super interface of the interface `LoginService`. But I think that's not right since the super interface is `Serializable`. Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**
I have edited my question with a full example. I don't think it's really duplicated because this example is a little bit more complex than those I found on this site.

Comment: it's not a static reference, as much as it's more of a "fully qualified" reference.

Comment: It's not static access, it's just a qualifier that explicitly says what class you're trying to access the `super` of. It's useful when trying to reference the outer class from inside an inner class.

Comment: If you looked at the context where this call happens, it would help you (and us) to find the explanation.

Comment: Comon guys let people answer my question please, as I explained it's more complex than the question marked as answered...

Comment: It's used to call the isLoggedIn() default method defined in the implemented LoginService interface. If you called just super.foo(), it would look in the superclass (i.e. Object), and would thus not find the method. Note that since your method doesn't do anything other then what the default method does, the whole method is unnecessary. Regarding your rant: that's why you should post clear questions from the start, with all the context necessary to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

when you are in an inner class doing

super.foo(); will call the foo() method of the super class of the inner class

calling

Outer.super.foo(); will call the foo() method of the super class of the outer class called Outer.

as in

```
class Outer extends OuterSuper {
    class Inner {
         public void someMethod() {
             Outer.super.foo();
         }
    }
}
```